# Delete photos from Desktop

Tags: photos, desktop

I exported a large number of photos by mistake from the photos application to my desktop.  How do I delete these photos?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of possibilities.

Firstly, you can try to press the undo keys: `cmd + z` (this probably will not work).

Otherwise you can try to use the Terminal, in the particular case you don't want to delete photos one by one. From the Terminal if you can run the following command: `rm ~/Desktop/*.extension` where extension stands for the extension of your pics. So for example if all the photos are JPEG you can run: `rm ~/Desktop/*.jpg`.

Please note that the use of this command will delete **all** the files in the desktop with the `.jpg` extension. So if you have even only one photo that you want to save from the desktop, you can't sue this tool.

Comment: To avoid making a mistake with the `cd` command that could lead to unintended data loss, you could type `rm ~/Desktop/*.jpg` to explicitly specify the path. (The `-r` flag in Mattia's second `rm` command is incorrect as it must be used with the `-d` flag, denoting `rm` operations to _directories_ and the contents therein.)

Comment: I applied your suggested edit @IconDaemon. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open a finder window and go to the desktop
2. change to list view
3. sort by type, so you can see just the jpegs
4. highlight/delete all jpegs